# When and how to validate HTML using contenteditable?

Tags: javascript, validation, contenteditable

I'm exploring the idea of using contenteditable on a website at visitor comments and at a message board.

As I only wish to accept a white-list of HTML tags and attributes the question of when and how should I validate the entered HTML content comes up.

How would you do it? What cross-browser solutions would you choose to use? What events could be useful?

Comment: @SLaks: I figured since I'm looking for general "best practice" advices instead of straight solutions I should mark this question as such. I could be wrong though of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)** is getting momentum these days.